# Enable authentication in mongoDb in Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: database, mongodb, authentication, ubuntu-16.04

I am usign **Ubuntu 16.04** and trying to enable auth in **mongodDb**

I created a new User by

```
db.createUser({
user:"Sun",
pwd:"Sun",
roles:[{role:"userAdmin",db:"pet"}]
})
```

I checked the user by

```
db.getUsers();
```

But I am still able to modify database without providing username and password

I tried to enable authorizations by the commands provided in [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) but its not working for me.

In my system to start the mongodb i have to write

```
sudo service mongod start
mongod
```

Please tell me how to enable auth in mongoDb

Comment: What's in the log file? `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` when you start mongo? Can you confirm your config file also has `security.authorization: enabled`

Comment: @user3788685 there is no security.authorization field in that file, please tell me what to do?

Comment: @user3788685 my system was crashed , i will let you know. Thank you for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be missing a config directive in your `mongod.conf` file.

check step 4 in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/index.html)

> Re-start the MongoDB instance with access control.
>
> Re-start the mongod instance with the --auth command line option or,
>   **if using a configuration file, the security.authorization setting**.

So in your config file you should have the line;

`security.authorization: enabled`

From a test box with CentOS the file is located at `/etc/mongod.conf` and should look something like this (Checking you paths are correct etc)

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true

processManagement:
  fork: true
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

security.authorization: enabled
```

You may also find it easier to use one of the [management](https://studio3t.com/) tools to manage you users with a GUI (presuming your on a Windows client) as its much easier then doing everything via the command line...

Once you have updated your config remember to restart your Mongod instance and check the log file at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` to make sure there are no errors on startup.

Remember you need to give your users access to any given database, I assign my users to each database, and not via the 'admin' db - I find it easier.

And lastly - If you find you have locked yourself out for some reason *don't panic!* just change the config line `security.authorization: enabled` to `disabled` and restart your instance you will the be able to log back in without any authentication!

The log file will also give you pointers as to access problems so check that while your testing/setting up your users.

And remember once finished *secure your deployment* and check you can't login or do anything without a valid login.